# how to run fastapi project in debug mode auto reload in vscode

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, fastapi

Started with fastapi python.

this is how I am string my server

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = FastAPI()

    def runServer(self, host: str, port: int,is_dev:bool):
        uvicorn.run(self.app, host=host, port=port,debug=is_dev)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Server()
    # read the environment variables
    host: str = os.environ['host']
    port: int = int(os.environ['port'])
    is_dev: bool = bool(os.environ['dev'])

    server.runServer(host, port, is_dev)
```

this ups the server but not running in auto reload mode if i make any changes.

even I tried

```
uvicorn.run(self.app, host=host, port=port, reload=is_dev)
```

reload is i guess not an option, thus causing the server to break.

i tried passing `--reload` args in launch.json even but still not working

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: FastAPI",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.py",
            "jinja": true,
            "args": ["--reload"],
            "env": {
                "host": "127.0.0.1",
                "port": "5555",
                "dev": "true"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

any idea? am i missing something?

Answer (score 47):

`uvicorn` will start in the reload mode only if the `app` argument is a string in the format `<module>:<app_instance>` and `reload` or `debug` argument are true. Like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("example:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=5000, reload=True)
```

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#running-programmatically):

> Note that the application instance itself can be passed instead of the app import string.
>
> `uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=5000, log_level="info")`
>
> However, this style only works if you are not using multiprocessing (`workers=NUM`) or reloading (`reload=True`), so we recommend using the import string style.

Comment: so instead of passing app object i need to pass the string and then only reload=True will work?

Comment: Yes, for reloading you should use string app argument

Comment: and what if i have to pass title and description to app for docs?

Comment: If like me you we confused about `example:app`: I'm assuming (because this theory worked for me) that `example` is the name of the file you are running the FastAPI app in so in this case: `example.py` whereas `app` comes from `app = FastAPI(debug=True)`

Comment: @alex_noname: Could you clarify indeed what’s the difference between passing the app as a string and passing it as a fastAPI object? How should we coin the string? Is there documentation on that?

Comment: When I do this, how come vs code does not show any variables?

Answer (score 0):

If your file is called handler.py, then the string should be "handler:app"